# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}{n}=0 \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+\ldots +a_{n}^2}{n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence of positive numbers. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+.....+a_{n}}{n}=0$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+.....+a_{n}^2}{n}=0$.

In this question, I proved $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+.....+a_{n}}{n}=0$ $\implies$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+.....+a_{n}^2}{n}=0$, by using A.M and G.M inequality.

I tried to prove the reverse inequality, but stuck in every attempt.

Can anyone suggest some hint for the reverse inequality?

Comment: How did you apply AM-GM for the forward direction?  Seems to me to be an immediate consequence of $(a_n)$ being nonnegative and bounded (so $0 \leq a_k^2 \leq Ma_k$ where $M$ is an upper bound for the sequence)

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us that
$$\frac{a_1 + a_2 +\cdots + a_n}{n} \leq \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2 +\cdots + a_n^2 }{n}}.$$
Since the latter converges to $0,$ we conclude that so does the former (since the sequence is positive, it is also bounded below by 0).

Comment: Sure? It seems that the OP is asking for this part only. The other part can be easily done as mentioned in the comment just beneath the question.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the boundedness assumption. The result is true even without boundedness, but that is quite difficult to prove.

Comment: Yes I also thought that you are referring to that. With the boundedness assumption it is much more easier.